# PHP query to fetch data from two table into one php script and display as one list

Tags: mysql

I have table  called **request**,from where  I am getting the data 
but my problem is that I want to get another table data to fetch in same php script that table name is **OEM** where no one table columns are similar.
I had 
table request like 
id,req_id,reg_id,mobile,i_id,user_id like this coulumns of REQUEST
and 
id,uname,name,email,address,mobile like this columns of OEM

where uname of oem and userid of request code are same 
uname = OEM10001
and 
user_id = OEM1001
how get all datat from both tables in one hit(fetch)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the pairs matched only, then `select * from request, oem where oem.uname=request.user_id`. If you need all records from one of tables (nulls for another table data when no matched record) use left/right join. If you need all records from both tables (paired matched, added nulls to non-matched) then emulate full join using union. - [akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)